# How to create a filter/effect for camera app?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, filter, camera

Actually I made a camera app by learning on YouTube and other platform but now I want to add some real time filter can anyone tell me how to make a filter that works in real time....? I'm newbie

Anyone ell me how to make a filter that work live

Answer (score 1):

Here the GitHub demo code you can implement it in your code.

[CameraView](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) that's you can try.

You can use [this](https://github.com/iamutkarshtiwari/Ananas) one also and [Editor Like WhatsApp](https://github.com/DroidNinja/Whatsapp-Like-PhotoEditor).

Comment: CameraView's filter can be use like Snapchat filters am I right?

Comment: Yes, You can use it depending on your requirements.